# Is this object modified in listener threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, concurrency, volatile

In the following snippet, assume two threads read/write from/to `results`. When the `eventListener` thread writes to `results`, will the blocked thread be able to access the latest results? If not, what utility (`volatile`, `AtomicReference`) will help?

```
private Object doStuff() {

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch( 1 );
    Object[] results = new Object[1];

    EventObjectListener eventListener = ( String topic, Object eventObject ) -> {
        results[0] = eventObject;
        latch.countDown();
    };

    eventReceiver.addEventListener( eventListener );

    doThingThatGeneratesEvent();

    int waitMagnitude = 10;
    TimeUnit waitUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
    try {
        latch.await( waitMagnitude, waitUnit );
    } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
        return null;
    } finally {
        eventReceiver.removeEventListener( eventListener );
    }

    return results[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `CountDownLatch` guarantees visibility¹, so if `await` doesn't time out `results[0]` will be good to go. However the code could probably be rewritten to be a little clearer.

¹ i.e. all writes from thread before `countDown()` [happen before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) the other thread returns from the `await()` call.

---

A *slightly* clearer (IMHO) version would use a `CompletableFuture` as follows:

```
CompletableFuture<Object> future = new CompletableFuture();

EventObjectListener eventListener = (topic, eventObject) -> 
        future.complete(eventObject);

try {
    return future.get(waitMagnitude, waitUnit);
} catch(Exception e) {
    return null;
} finally {
    eventReceiver.removeEventListener(eventListener);
}
```

Comment: Is the read of results[0] going directly to memory? Do you know the path that the JVM takes in getting the value?

Comment: @125 I'm not sure what you mean by path, but it's guaranteed to work by the memory model. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks that answered my question! If it's not too much to ask, could you describe any changes that would make the code clearer?

Comment: Well, actually the `CountDownLatch` is pretty fine here. However you could get rid of the single size array by using a `CompletableFuture` and complete that from the listener with the results. I'll edit it in.

Comment: Interesting, haven't seen that before. I was using `AtomicReference` under the assumption there was a concurrency problem, but I like this approach better. Thanks again

Comment: If you don’t need the timeout, you could simply use `join()`. Then, you don’t have to deal with checked exceptions and removing the `catch(Exception e) { return null; }` would make the code much cleaner than transforming any kind of exception to a `null` result. By the way, you can also use simpler lambda syntax: `EventObjectListener eventListener = (topic, eventObject) -> future.complete(eventObject);`